# Extending a Javascript class when both are within a return statement of a closure

Tags: javascript, function, class, object, closures

I'm still learning about closures, so this might be impossible given their nature, so bear with me. I have a global variable that is an object returned from a closure. Some of this object's properties are classes.

```
var TEST = (function() {
    return {
        Base: class {
            constructor() {}
            hello() { console.log("Hello"); }
        },
        Extended: class { // what do I do here?
            constructor() {}
        }
    }
})();
```

I am able to declare `var b = new TEST.Base()` and call the `hello()` function on that var, working as expected.

I would like to make `TEST.Extended` extend `TEST.Base` and have access to its own `hello()` function, and have not had any luck thus far. Thing's I've tried:

```
// 1 - ReferenceError: Base is not defined
Extended: class extends Base {...}

// 2 - TypeError: TEST is undefined
Extended: class extends TEST.Base {...}

// 3 - ReferenceError: NamedClass is not defined
Base: class NamedClass {...},
Extended: class OtherNamedClass extends NamedClass {...}

// 4 - TypeError: TEST is undefined
Base: class NamedClass {...},
Extended: class OtherNamedClass extends TEST.NamedClass {...}
```

I'm unsure of any other options. Is this possible in Javascript?

Comment: `TEST is undefined` should be all the info you need. Your 2nd option should work fine once you fix that. Nor is closure relevant here because you aren't hiding anything in it.

Comment: How am I able to define `TEST` there if it's "still being defined" when I'm defining `Extended`? I do realize that the closure term is irrelevant in this simple example, I have a larger case where stuff is indeed hidden and thought they might be connected.

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple problems here.

First, if you are using classes that means that the file you are declaring it in is almost certainly being treated as a *module*, meaning top-level variables are not automatically visible outside of the file they are defined in. You'll have to `import` TEST or do something like `window.TEST = (function(){...`. Speaking of your function wrapper...

While the IIFE does create a closure that's not in any way relevant because you aren't closing over anything: as you've written it the wrapper is meaningless.

```
var TEST = {
  Base: class { /* definition goes here */ }
};
```

Is the same as what you wrote. In order for the closure to have any utility you would need to *hide* something in it.

```
var TEST = (function() {
  var private = whatever;
  return {
    Base: class {}
  };
})();
```

The `return`ed object closes over private.

Now on to your *actual* question.

How to export the extended class as part of the TEST object. Short answer: 
you can't do it that way. It would need to refer to `TEST.Base` and you can't do that in the object definition that way. There are several alternatives, but here's what I'd go with if you don't want Base exposed:

```
var TEST = (function() {
  var Base = class { /* class definition goes here */ };
  return {
    Base,
    Extended: class extends Base { /* extension definition goes here */ }
  };
})();
```

Note that this is still somewhat unnecessary. You could just as easily write

```
var Base = class {};
var TEST = { Base, Extended: class extends Base {} };
```

and in fact now that we have ES 6 Modules (or can reliably fake them) this is indeed how it *should* be written (IMHO). You can decide whether to export Base by itself or only have it accessed through your API object TEST.